# Stopping kill command

Tags: ruby, linux, process

I have ruby application.
My application consist of some scheduled jobs, which take places at every 2 or 3 hrs or more continuously.
I regularly make changes to application, therefore i have to kill the application and re-run it again.
I generally follow these 3 steps

```
ps -ef|grep rackup
kill -9 PID
rake run
```

So therefore its scheduled jobs get effected, if they are under execution...
Is it any way to stop kill -9 command till jobs get finished (may be some locks or script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rescue `SystemExit` exceptions, or use `trap` or `at_exit` signal handlers. [More info here](http://www.bigfastblog.com/ruby-exit-exit-systemexit-and-at_exit-blunder).

Answer (score 1):

The `SIGKILL` (from the original `POSIX.1-1990` standard, defined as integer value `9`) cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.

Instead of sending a `SIGKILL` you probably want to send a `SIGTERM` (integer value `15`) so you can [trap it in your application](http://art.csoft.net/2007/12/07/trapping-signals-in-ruby/).

Without seeing the actual code of your application, it's difficult to tell you exactly how you should do it, but a good approach to start with is to set a variable in your signal handler, and check its status at some point in your application where it can *gracefully* terminate.